# (IONIC 2) Error : socket.io integrate express, GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LvraMVg 404 (Not Found) (WEBRTC)

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, ionic2, webrtc

I got an error, I'm trying to access my node server from ionic2,

information :

1.i am building node server on my own laptop
2.when I'm running ionic serve, all working normal.. chat no problem, all good.

problem : 
1. when I'm running it on android device, using command `ionic cordova run android`, everything error, when I check the inspect -> console,

and this is what the console says :

GET http://myIpIsHere:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LvraMVg 404 (Not Found)

I will attach the code below.
server.js

```
var socket = require('socket.io'),
http = require('http'),
server = http.createServer(),
socket = socket.listen(server);

socket.on('connection', function(connection) {
    console.log('User Connected');

    connection.on('sendid', function(id){
        socket.emit('id', id);
        console.log('triger isi apa : ', id);
    });

    connection.on('message2', function(msg){
        console.log('triger isi msg apa :', msg);
        socket.emit('message2', msg);
    });

    connection.on('message', function(msg){
        console.log('triger isi msg apa :', msg);
        socket.emit('message', msg);
    });
});

server.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server started');
});
```

this my ionic2, try for access the server

```
this.statisticServer="http://myIpIsHere:3000/";
console.log('server :', this.statisticServer );
this.socket = io(this.statisticServer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

already solve,

i added whitelist plugin,

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist --save

hope this case help other on the future..